# Dynamically load library in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm try to load and call some methods dicamicaly libraries in Codeigniter like

```
$plugins = array('paypal', 'captcha');
foreach($plugins as $plugin){
    $this->load->library($plugin);
    //The problem appear when I'm try to call some method...
    echo $this->[$plugin]->hello_world();
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: echo $this-[$plugin]->hello_world(); //This fail

Comment: echo $this->$plugin->hello_world(); //Fail
echo $this->{$plugin}->hello_world(); //Fail
I don't kwow the correct method to make this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ohh I found the sollution.
$plugin = "".$plugin."";
$this->$plugin->hello_world();

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it by following code. for more you can visit [Codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::library)

```
$this->load->library($plugin,null,'object_name');
$this->object_name->hello_world();
```

for remove instance of `$this->object_name`. better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062291/how-to-destroy-codeigniter-library-instance#29062785)

```
unset($this->object_name);
```

or

```
$this->object_name = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try loading it in the autoload.php file of CI

Comment: we don't have keep all library to loaded in every page. its effect the performance