# How to destroy Codeigniter library instance

Tags: php, codeigniter, instance, destroy

I would like to know if there is any way I can destroy a Codeigniter library instance.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
$this->load->library('my_library');
/**
    Code goes here
**/
$this->my_library->destoy_instance();
```

The reason I need to do this is because I need to liberate RAM memory while executing a large scripts.

Any help will be greatly appresiated.

Answer (score 6):

You can do simply like that by using [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) or setting `null`.

```
unset($this->my_library);
```

OR

```
$this->my_library = null;
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667137/the-difference-between-unset-and-null#13667734) is also worth reading for you to know detail about these two ways.

**Edit**

There is no built-in method to destroy loaded library object. But you can do it by extending `Loader` class. And then load and unload library from that class. Here is my sample code ..

application/libraries/custom_loader.php

```
class Custom_loader extends CI_Loader {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function unload_library($name) {
        if (count($this->_ci_classes)) {
            foreach ($this->_ci_classes as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == $name) {
                    unset($this->_ci_classes[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (count($this->_ci_loaded_files)) {
            foreach ($this->_ci_loaded_files as $key => $value)
            {
                $segments = explode("/", $value);
                if (strtolower($segments[sizeof($segments) - 1]) == $name.".php") {
                    unset($this->_ci_loaded_files[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $name = ($name != "user_agent") ? $name : "agent";
        unset($CI->$name);
    }
}
```

In your controller ..

```
$this->load->library('custom_loader');
// To load library
$this->custom_loader->library('user_agent');
$this->custom_loader->library('email');

// To unload library
$this->custom_loader->unload_library('user_agent');
$this->custom_loader->unload_library('email');
```

Hope it will be useful.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it does seem to put the variables to null, however is there a way to completely destroy the object on Codeigniter? The problem is that it is not liberating any memory.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I found a solution to this if you need to re-create the same object within the same controller. The trick it to pass in the third property which is a custom name you can assign the object.

```
$this->load->library('my_library', $my_parameters, 'my_library_custom_name');
```

If you just want to unset the object PHP will take care of that. You can confirm using a destructor on your class.

```
public function __destruct() {

    // do something to show you when the object has been destructed

}
```